# Search in a table whether a record is present previously

Tags: sql

I have an `orders` table. I want to search if the customer has ordered for the first time or not. We can use `email_id` field in orders table to check it. But how can I check it using an SQL query? That is, I want to search the *first order* of the particular customer. How can I do it?

Comment: Record date time of the Order as well and then get minimum order date of a particular customer or just to check whether it is first time or not then `select count(1) from orders where customer_email = given_email`

Comment: why are you looking for first record??

Comment: I want to have results for new customers and existing customers. So i want to search if the customer has placed the order for first time.

Comment: @user818671 try my solution below.

Comment: It sounds like you want to know if there is any record in the orders table, not just when the first one was made?

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

`select * from orders where email_id='myid@mysite.com'`

if there is data in this query, it means that particular customer is not ordering for first time...

Hope this is what you want...

### Update 1

Try this...

`select emailid, count(emailid) as total from order where 1=1 group by emailid order by total`

this will give you below output

```
emailid       total
++++++++++++++++++++
my1@mm.com      1
my2@mm.com      4
my3@mm.com      6
```

Also check what you get for `select emailid, count(emailid) as total from order where total>1 group by emailid order by total`
As I don't have sql here, I can't check :(

### Good Luck

Comment: i cannot specify an email id like you did in above query i need to select it from orders table only.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT email_id, IF(COUNT(email_id) > 0, 'NOT', 'First Time') AS Status
FROM `Orders`
WHERE email_id = 'EMAILADDRESSHERE'
GROUP BY email_id
```

Answer (score 0):

First order:


T-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM orders 
WHERE email_id='myid@mysite.com'
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```

PostgreSQL / MySQL:

```
SELECT 
FROM orders 
WHERE email_id='myid@mysite.com'
ORDER BY order_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Interbase:

```
SELECT FIRST 1 SKIP 0 
FROM orders 
WHERE email_id='myid@mysite.com'
ORDER BY order_date DESC
```